# MySQL Sum operation based on other column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
Date       | Name  | Pick  | Amount
-----------+-------+-------+-------
2018-01-01 | Alice | Apple |      2
2018-01-01 | Alice | Grape |      3
2018-01-01 | Bob   | Apple |      4
2018-01-02 | Alice | Apple |      5
2018-01-02 | Bob   | Grape |      6
```

What is the SQL statement that produce result like below?

```
Name  | Apple | Grape | Total
------+-------+-------+------
Alice |     7 |     3 |    10
Bob   |     4 |     6 |    10
```

Comment: FWIW, I would handle this display issue in application code, if that was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
select name, 
       sum(case when pick = 'Apple' then amount else 0  end) Apple,
       sum(case when pick = 'Grape' then amount else 0  end) Grape,
       sum(case when pick in ('Apple', 'Grape') then amount else 0 end) Total
from table t
group by name;
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Using `CASE` condition, it will be possible.

Try this:

```
select name
    ,sum(case when pick = 'Apple' then amount end)Apple
    ,sum(case when pick = 'Grape' then amount end)Grape
    ,sum(case when pick = 'Apple' then amount end)
        +sum(case when pick = 'Grape' then amount end)Total
from your_table
group by name
```

Comment: Thank you. Very fast respond.

Answer (score 2):

the is also a way to calculate your result, using aggregate function and `or`

```
select name, 
           sum(case when pick = 'Apple' then amount else 0  end) Apple,
           sum(case when pick = 'Grape' then amount else 0  end) Grape,
           sum(case when pick in('Apple','Grape') then amount  else 0 end) Total
    from  tableA
    group by name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c56c/4

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, 
sum(if(Pick='Apple', Amount, 0)) as Apple, 
sum(if(Pick='Grape', amount, 0)) as Grape 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested queries. One to calculate the grapes and the apples and one to calculate the total. The advantage is that you have the logic for calculation of each column on a single place and the calculation of the total is a bit more visible

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    Apple,
    Grape,
    Apple + Grape as Total
FROM (
  SELECT
      `name` as Name,
      SUM(IF(pick = 'Apple', amount, 0)) as Apple,
      SUM(IF(pick = 'Grape', amount, 0)) as Grape
  FROM test
  GROUP BY name
) AS t1
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gvwsLszpnzHTRrdHSmiWj7/0)